# Gatling with Karate: data from feeder has undefined values in feature

Tags: performance, karate

Data from the feeder are not passing in the feature. How should I pass data from feeder to feature? I will describe my code here:

**Simulation**

```
  val protocol: KarateProtocol = karateProtocol(
    "/" -> Nil,
    "/" -> pauseFor("get" -> 3, "post" -> 5)
  )

  private val feeder = Iterator.continually(Map(
    "uri" -> s"https://$runEnv-url.com",
    "token" -> getApiAuthToken(userLogin, userPassword, userAccount).getToken,
    "userId" -> getApiAuthToken(userLogin, userPassword, userAccount).getUserID
  ))

  val scn: ScenarioBuilder =
    scenario("Scenario name")
      .feed(feeder)
      .exec(session => {
        println(session)
        session
      })
      .exec(karateFeature("classpath:specs/api.feature"))

  setUp(
    scn.inject(constantUsersPerSec(1) during(1 seconds)).protocols(protocol)
  )
```

**Feature:**

```
Feature: Scenario name

  Background:
    * url __gatling.uri
    * header Authentication = 'Token ' + __gatling.token

  Scenario: Get User Details
    Given path 'users', __gatling.userId
    When method get
    Then status 200
    And print response
```

And as result, I'm getting `undefined` instead of data from the feeder.

**Logs:**

```
When method get
http call failed after 92 milliseconds for url: /users
```

**UPD:** code from answer works, but get value from session still returns `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `karateSet()` (new in 1.1.0) as shown in this [example](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/v1.1.0/karate-gatling/src/test/scala/mock/CatsChainedSimulation.scala#L32)

Something like this should work in your Scala simulation:

```
.feed(feeder)
.exec(karateSet("token", session => session("token").as[String]))
```

Please read the docs also: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling#chaining

And if still stuck, follow this process please: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: I have reused code from an example, but still can't get value from the session. What a way to get it?
I've tried ```url __gatling.uri``` but still values are undefineded

Comment: @TarasHoruk I give up

Comment: Peter, last question, what key should I use in the feature? __gatling, __karate, _arg, #() return null or undefined